# why type="number" accepting 'e' character?

Tags: html, input

can anybody here explain why input `type=number` accepts `e` character? it really confuses me and i'm wondering about it .

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Because in addition to the letter `e`, there is also a **number** `e` (which represents **[exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation)**).

If you really want to exclude these, you can prevent them by targetting character code `69`, and preventing the default behaviour for the `keypress` event with **[`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)** if the character is entered:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.which === 69) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

**EDIT** Modified the event and the condition to `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 8):

e is the exponent. This allows a user to enter a number such as `4e3`, which means 4×10<sup>3</sup>.

Try entering `4e3` in the box, and then press the up step button: in Chrome this will change to show `4001`

Comment: hey, thanks for clear feedback!